# R create a spatial weight matrix having information on distance between points

Tags: r, distance, spatial

I have a dataset ordered in long format that reflects the origin, destination and distance between them (in km). A subsample of my data considering the first individual looks like this:

```
              from_id                 to_id  distance
1 @34, Exeter College            AMT Coffee 0.8535553
2 @34, Exeter College Asia Chinese Takeaway 3.3461476
3 @34, Exeter College       BBQ Kebab House 3.3157992
4 @34, Exeter College            Best Kebab 1.1460261
5 @34, Exeter College    Bodrum Kebab House 0.7994965
```

My purpose is to create a weight matrix and my question is whether there any possible way to do so considering that I only have distance information.

A dput of my data is below:

```
structure(list(from_id = c("@34, Exeter College", "@34, Exeter College", 
"@34, Exeter College", "@34, Exeter College", "@34, Exeter College"
), to_id = c("AMT Coffee", "Asia Chinese Takeaway", "BBQ Kebab House", 
"Best Kebab", "Bodrum Kebab House"), distance = c(0.853555311083426, 
3.34614761216615, 3.31579922025365, 1.14602607357899, 0.799496508603144
)), .Names = c("from_id", "to_id", "distance"), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Not sure about what you mean with weight. Is this the influence of one on the other ? In that case, a common weighting is the inverse distance like `w = 1/d^2`

Comment: Thanks @SébastienRochette. Would be possible to create a matrix object? My final purpose is to run a spatial regression model.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a matrix from your table using

```
dat_mat <- xtabs(distance ~ from_id + to_id, data = data)
```

Then create the inverse distance weights

```
inv_w <- 1/dat_mat^2
```